# rapidjson::Document in std::pair

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, linker-errors, std-pair, rapidjson

I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >::GenericValue(rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> > const&)
```

This error jumps at me when I try to return the `rapidjson::Document` in a pair:

```
typedef std::pair<rapidjson::Document, std::string> ProcessedResponseResult;

ProcessedResponseResult ProcessResponse(HttpResponse* response)
{
    rapidjson::Document jsonDoc;
    ...
    return ProcessedResponseResult(jsonDoc, std::string());
}
```

If it helps, rapidjson is a header only library.

Why can't I return the pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct a `ProcessedResponseResult`, it will call the copy constructor of `rapidjson::Document`, but in the file `rapidjason/document.h`, to prevent from copying the `rapidjson::Document` object, it declares a private copy constructor, and doesn't implement it, so this causes the linker error.

```
//! Copy constructor is not permitted.
private:
    GenericValue(const GenericValue& rhs);
```

If your reason for using `std::pair` is just to return 2 values from the function, I'd recommend passing the `jsonDoc` by reference.

Comment: I guess my only choice is dynamic allocation (`new`), or passing the document by reference.. That makes a lot of sense, I don't want to copy a possible humungous JSON document.

Comment: lol, and eliminate the chance of leaking. Yeah, I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: Damn, I wish they just did something like this: `explicit CustomString(const std::string& str);` ... explicit FTW.